Azure Data Factory - Expression cannot be evaluated because property 'firstrow' doesn't exist
I have a step in my ADF pipeline that is failing with the following error:
Operation on target LastRun failed: The expression 'formatDateTime(activity('Last Run').output.firstRow.lastdate, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')' cannot be evaluated because property 'firstRow' doesn't exist, available properties are 'effectiveIntegrationRuntime, durationInQueue'.

Whats interesting is that, if I rerun the pipeline it then works as expected. Does anyone know why this might be failing first time, but then working after?
The bit that is failing with this error is a 'Set Variable' following a lookup:


The lookup is a simple SQL script to a snowflake database:
select max(PROCESSINGCOMPLETE) as lastdate from schema.loadcontrol where status = 'Completed' and filedirection = 'Inbound'

and the set variable is just to convert the date into a better format:
@formatDateTime(activity('Last Run').output.firstRow.lastdate, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')

The error message says that firstrow isnt a valid option, but its there in the query builder:

Works 9 times out of 10, but for the tenth time I have no idea why it doesnt like it. Has anyone come across this before?
Update:
Images to show the data previewing correctly with a single row of data:



The error message says that the output of lookup activity does not have first row property.  This can happen either when first row only option is not checked in lookup activity or when the lookup activity does not return any value.

Option:1

To get the FirstRow property , you need to check the First row only check box in the lookup activity settings.


The output Json of lookup activity after checking the first row only checkbox.
{
    "firstRow": {
        "lastdate": "2000-01-01"
    },
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "xxxx",
    "billingReference": {
        XXXXX
    },
    "durationInQueue": {
        XXX
    }
}

Option:2
-Even after checking first row only option in the lookup activity, if you are getting the error, then this can happen when there is no data returned from lookup activity.

To check if the lookup activity has value, click on preview data and check if there is data in the lookup activity.


Then change the logic to get some default value when there is no value in lookup activity.

Hi there Aswin, thanks for the reply. The 'First Row Only' is set and enabled, and when I preview the result it returns a value: 2024-04-10T09:40:01.055+00:00
So it seems both of those things wouldn't cause the issue? At least not to error once and then work fine next time

Can you share the output Json of lookup activity ?

The lookup output that happens before the set variable failure is (apologies for formatting):
{
"effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "adf-MIR (UK South)",
"durationInQueue": {
"integrationRuntimeQueue": 0
}
}

Did you preview the data by giving same query in the lookup activity? Can u share the screenshot of data preview once.

Yeah I previewed the data with the same query. I have attached a screenshot showing the output in the original question :)

I can see this activity is inside for-each activity?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
